# Jetpack navigation fails to navigate to LoginScreen.kt

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

While navigating to other screens, Jetpack compose navigation in `SignUpScreen.kt` fails to navigateTo `LoginScreen.kt`. I used sealed class to define the screens and data object to define sub-screens. What seems to be the problem?

```
package com.example.bettehomes.presentation.authscreens

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.CircularProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHost
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.R
import com.example.bettehomes.components.*
import com.example.bettehomes.data.signup.SignupViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.data.signup.SignupUIEvent
import com.example.bettehomes.navigation.BetteHomesAppRouter
import com.example.bettehomes.navigation.Screens
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@Composable
fun SignUpScreen(signupViewModel: SignupViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState()}
    Scaffold( snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
        },

    ){it
        //Screen content
     Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(28.dp)
                ) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                        NormalTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.hello))
                        HeadingTextComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.create_account))
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.first_name),
                            painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.FirstNameChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.firstNameError
                        )

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.last_name),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profile),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.LastNameChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.lastNameError
                        )

                        MyTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.email),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.message),
                            onTextChanged = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.EmailChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.emailError
                        )

                        PasswordTextFieldComponent(
                            labelValue = stringResource(id = R.string.password),
                            painterResource = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_lock),
                            onTextSelected = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.PasswordChanged(it))
                            },
                            errorStatus = signupViewModel.registrationUIState.value.passwordError
                        )

                        CheckboxComponent(value = stringResource(id = R.string.terms_and_conditions),
                            onTextSelected = {
                                BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.TermsAndConditionsScreen)
                            },
                            onCheckedChange = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.PrivacyPolicyCheckBoxClicked(it))
                            }
                        )

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

                        ButtonComponent(
                            value = stringResource(id = R.string.register),
                            onButtonClicked = {
                                signupViewModel.onEvent(SignupUIEvent.RegisterButtonClicked)
                                if (signupViewModel.userExists.value){
                                scope.launch { snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("The Email address is already in use!") }
                            }},
                            isEnabled = signupViewModel.allValidationsPassed.value
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

                        DividerTextComponent()

                        LoginClickableTextComponent(tryingToLogin = true,onTextSelected = {
                            BetteHomesAppRouter.navigateTo(Screens.LoginScreen)
                        })
                    }

                }

                if(signupViewModel.signUpInProgress.value) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }

            }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultPreviewOfSignUpScreen() {
    SignUpScreen()
}
```

AppRouter.kt

```
package com.example.bettehomes.navigation

import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf

sealed class Screens(val route: String) {

    data object SignUpScreen : Screens("SignUpScreen")
    data object TermsAndConditionsScreen : Screens("termsAndConditions")
    data object LoginScreen : Screens("loginScreen")
    data object HomeScreen : Screens("homeScreen")
    data object MapScreen : Screens("mapScreen")
    data object GeoMarkerScreen : Screens("geoMarkerScreen")
}


object BetteHomesAppRouter {

    private var currentScreen: MutableState<Screens> = mutableStateOf(Screens.MapScreen)

    fun navigateTo(destination : Screens){
        currentScreen.value = destination
    }
```

Comment: What does fails to navigate imply? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Abhimanyu No, there are no errors on the LogCat, it shows the message `{Login}`, but it does not actually navigateTo LoginScreen.

Comment: Can you share where the `{Login}` is printed/Logged in the code?

Comment: It is located at the bottom of `SignUpScreen.kt` in `LoginClickableTextComponent`

Comment: @Abhimanyu I still didn't figure out what's wrong.